# PHP format a number to have no decimal places?

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have a number (as string) like this: **1.00000**

How can I reformat such numbers to only look like **1**?

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`number_format()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
echo number_format('1.000000'); // prints 1
```

Or use [`intval()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
echo intval('1.000000'); // prints 1
```

Or cast it as an integer

```
echo (int) '1.000000'; // prints 1
```

Comment: Ah, I already looked at that function but missed that point :). Thanks

Comment: Number_format would be preferred as it would also allow to define a specific thousands separator should the need arise

Answer (score 0):

You can use the floor method for it to stay as a float

```
floor(1.000000)
```